# add timestamps related fields from existing unix timestamp field dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, time-series

I am new to Python Programing language. For my learning I took sample sales data that contain **orderid, product_name, no_items, amount, total_amount, sale_time**. I am using pandas to load the data.

```
import pandas as pd
sale_data = pd.read_csv("test_sale_data.csv")
```

**sale_time** field have unix time and I am using **to_datetime** function to convert into readable datetime format.

```
sale_data['sale_time_new'] = to_datetime(sale_data['sale_time'],time='s')

# 1284101485 --> 2010-09-10 06:51:25
```

So I am trying to add timestamps related fields to existing sale_data dataframe like **Year, Quarter, YearQuarter, Month, YearMonth, Week, YearWeek, date, day, datehour, hour**.

```
1284101485 --> 2010, Q3, 2010-Q3, 09, 201009, 36, 2010-WW36, 2010-09-10, 10, 2010-09-10 06:00:00 , 06
```

How can I do in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors) in pandas; all of [these components](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/timeseries.html#time-date-components) are available. For your use case:

```
sale_data['sale_time_new'] = to_datetime(sale_data['sale_time'],time='s')

# Year
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.year
# Quarter
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.quarter
# YearQuarter
'{y}-{q}'.format(y=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.year, q=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.year)
# Month
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.month
# YearMonth
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.year*100 + sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.month
# Week
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.week
# YearWeek
'{y}-WW{w}'.format(y=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.year, w=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.week)
# date
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.date
# day
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.day
# datehour
'{y}-{m}-{d} {h}:00:00'.format(y=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.year, m=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.month, d=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.day, h=sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.hour)
# hour
sale_data['sale_time_new'].dt.hour
```

Comment: Thanks Kartik.

Also, I am adding another field based on "hour" field and "hour" field have values like 0,1,2,3,4,5,...23

if hour <= 8 then 'Bucket 1'
elif hour >=9 and hour <= 10 then 'Bucket 2'
elif hour >= 11 and hour <= 17 then 'Bucket 3'
else 'Bucket 4 

How to write this condition while creating new field ?

Comment: You could use nested `.where` or `.mask` methods to do it. Or you could just write the conditions by hand. Its easy enough to do. Look up pandas dataframe where. If you think my answer helped you, please mark as answered.

Comment: I am new to this forum and how can I mark your reply as answer.

Comment: You see the up arrow, a 0 and a down arrow beside my answer? And below that you will see a tick mark. Click on that tick mark, it will mark it as answer. And if you like my answer, you can also click the up arrow to up vote my answer. Its like a thumbs up.